# php foreach getting values from an array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, multidimensional-array

I am having trouble accessing the values in an array,  the array looks like this,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1661
            [code] => 849651318
            [job_status] => 4
            [looking_for] => Lorem ipsum
            [keywords_education] => Derby University
            [sector_id_csv] => 10,21,9,22,26
            [last_job_title_1] => Programmer
            [last_job_employer_1] => HBOS
            [city] => Bury
            [expected_salary_level] => LEVEL_2
            [education_level] => COLLEGE
            [job_looking_for] => 
            [is_contract] => Y
            [is_permanent] => N
            [is_temporary] => Y
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 402
            [code] => 849650059
            [job_status] => 3
            [looking_for] => Lorem ipsum
            [keywords_education] => Paris College
            [sector_id_csv] => 27,22,19,21,12
            [last_job_title_1] => Programmer
            [last_job_employer_1] => HSBC
            [city] => Bury
            [expected_salary_level] => LEVEL_2
            [education_level] => COLLEGE
            [job_looking_for] => 
            [is_contract] => N
            [is_permanent] => Y
            [is_temporary] => Y
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1653
            [code] => 849651310
            [job_status] => 3
            [looking_for] => Lorem ipsum
            [keywords_education] => Crewe University
            [sector_id_csv] => 27,15,19,21,24
            [last_job_title_1] => Programmer
            [last_job_employer_1] => ICI
            [city] => Bury
            [expected_salary_level] => LEVEL_2
            [education_level] => UNIVERSITY
            [job_looking_for] => 
            [is_contract] => N
            [is_permanent] => Y
            [is_temporary] => Y
        )

)
```

I am trying to get the values out, I have tried doing the following,

```
foreach ($result as $rslt) {
    echo $rslt->id;
}
```

I have also tried,

```
foreach ($result as $rslt) {
    $rslt['id'];
}
```

But none of this works, I dont know why, can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To point out a few things and hopefully clarify any confusion, in your first example:

```
foreach ($result as $rslt) {
    echo $rslt->id;
}
```

The arrow operator (`->`) is misused. It's commonly used to invoke a method on a class object, in your case `$rslt` would be a class object and `id` would be a method, which isn't the case.

In your second example,

```
foreach ($result as $rslt) {
    $rslt['id'];
}
```

You almost hit the nail on the head, but you had forgot to call `echo` or `print` to output the value onto the screen.

Also, your `$result` array has a sub-array at index `0`, so that would need to change

```
$rslt['id'];
```

to, along with the `echo` or `print` statement.

```
echo $rslt[0]['id'];
```

Answer (score 1):

The second is correct, but you're missing an `echo` or `print`

```
echo $rslt['id'];
```

From the example code you give it's not clear what `$result` is.
If `$result` encompasses all the listed arrays, you will have to do

```
foreach($result as $rslt) {
    echo $rslt[0]['id'];
}
```

Further reference:

- http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php
- http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.print.php
- http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($result as $rslt) {
    echo $rslt[0]['id'];
}
```